# How to show page only when all children were fully loaded in Angular 5?

Tags: angular

I have a page with few child components:

```
<div class="wrapper" *ngIf="isPageFullyLoaded">

  <header></header>

  <main class="content">
      <trip-list></trip-list> 
  </main>

  <footer></footer>
 </div>
```

The ts file include the following:

```
...
public isPageFullyLoaded = false;
...
ngAfterContentInit() {
        this.isPageFullyLoaded = true;
    }

The child trips-list:
<section *ngIf="trips">
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let data of trips" >
...
```

The trips list is loaded using rest api:

```
getTrips() {
    this.fundService.getTrips().subscribe(
      data => { this.trips= data; }, 
      err => console.error(err),
      () => console.log(this.trips)
    );
  }
```

I've tried also ngAfterViewInit

I need a way to show the main div only when the children were fully loaded.
I can't used *ngIf inside the div cause the children component won't loaded.

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: You have a way to know that the children are loaded?

Comment: Use some boolean value in `ngAfterViewChecked()`

Comment: ngAfterViewChecked is good idea but where to use the boolean and how in the template ?

Comment: @user2304483 wrap the content of your component in a `div` and use  `*ngIf`

Comment: I've already tried this and what  I see is that the footer and header loaded first and then the other children. I need the show the page when all is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the property `allChildrenLoaded` indicates that the children are loaded, you can bind it to the `hidden` property of the main div. Contrary to `ngIf`, which loads the element only when the condition is satisfied, the `hidden` property hides an element that is actually present in the DOM.

```
<div class="wrapper" [hidden]="!allChildrenLoaded">
  <child1></child1>
  <child2 *ngFor="let value of values"></child2>
  <trip-list (loaded)="onTripListLoaded()"></trip-list>
</div>
```

---

You can use `@ViewChildren` and the `changes` event of the `QueryList` to detect when the components are loaded:

```
export class ParentComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChildren(Child1Component) children1: QueryList<Child1Component>;
  @ViewChildren(Child2Component) children2: QueryList<Child2Component>;

  private child1Loaded = false;
  private children2Loaded = false;
  private tripListLoaded = false;

  private expectedChildren2Count = 5; // Expected number of Child2Component to be loaded

  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.child1Loaded = this.children1.length > 0;
    this.children2Loaded = this.children2.length === expectedChildren2Count;
    this.cd.detectChanges(); // To avoid possible runtime error

    this.children1.changes.subscribe(() => {
      this.child1Loaded = this.children1.length > 0;
    });
    this.children2.changes.subscribe(() => {
      this.children2Loaded = this.children2.length === expectedChildren2Count;
    });
  }

  onTripListLoaded() {
    this.tripListLoaded = true;
  }

  get allChildrenLoaded(): boolean {
    return this.child1Loaded && this.child2Loaded && this.tripListLoaded;
  }
}
```

---

In the `trip-list` component, you can emit a `loaded` event when the content is loaded. The parent component uses event binding to handle that event (see the markup above).

```
@Output() public loaded: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

getTrips() {
    this.fundService.getTrips().subscribe(
      data => { 
        this.trips= data; 
        this.loaded.emit();
      }, 
      err => console.error(err),
      () => console.log(this.trips)
    );
  }
```

---

See [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/template-driven-form-2-dnfada) for a demo.

Comment: You check `this.children1.length > 0`, but what if we have repeatable child components, for example 3 same components, which have different loading time? Looks like this check will become `true` when any one component will be rendered, but not all of them.

Comment: If you know how many of them should be loaded, you can do this: `this.children1Loaded = this.children1.length === expectedChild1Count;`.

Comment: @CommercialSuicide - I updated the answer to account for that case. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: The code above worked but it doesn't solve the problem. The header and footer loaded first and only then the heavy part.

Comment: Do you monitor the presence of the `trip-list` component with `ViewChildren`? If so, it may be the inner content of that component that is not loaded yet. I cannot tell because I don't see the code for the `trip-list` component.

Comment: I added the trip-list child in to the original question.

Comment: I updated the answer to account for the `trip-list` component.

Comment: The event from child to parent solve the problem! thanks ConnorsFan.